# Fixed Length Text File to SQL Data Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, xml-parsing

I have a text file (~100,000+ rows), where each column is a fixed length and I need to get it into a SQL Server database table. Each one of our clients are required to get this data, but each text file is slightly different so we have to manually go in and adjust the character spacing in a SQL stored procedure.

I was wondering if there is a way that we can use XML/XSD/XSLT instead. This way, I would not have to go in and manually edit the stored procedures.

What we do currently is this:

```
1.) SQL server stored procedure reads a text file from the disk
2.) Each record is split into an XML element and dumped into a temporary table
3.) Using SQL Server's string manipulation, each element is parsed
4.) Each column is dumped into
```

For clarification, here are a couple of examples...

One client's text file would have the following:

```
Name [12 Characters]
Employer [20 Characters]
Income [7 Characters]
Year-Qtr [5 Characters]

JIM JONES  HOMERS HOUSE OF HOSE100000 20113
```

Another client's text file would have the following:

```
Year-Qtr [5 Characters]
Income [7 Characters]
Name [12 Characters]
Employer [20 Characters]

20113100000 JIM JONES  HOMERS HOUSE OF HOSE
```

They basically all have the same fields, some may have a couple more are a couple less, just in different orders.

Comment: Could you demonstrate a difference in the Text files?  Maybe that will help flush out a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work, but have you looked into the `BULK INSERT` command? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225968%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: We used to use BULK INSERT, but it required a bunch of permissions that would sometimes get overlooked when IT decided to move databases, files and folders.

Comment: i think i do not understand the problem - what is the reason to manually edit the stored procedures? what is the purpose of using XML if you want to insert some text data into a database table??

Comment: The stored procedure parses out the different values from the longer string/record then inserts them into the table. I bring up XML thinking that maybe doing the parsing at the application level, then passing XML to the database may be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server xml processing functions to import a fixed length text file seems like a backwards way of doing things (no offense).

You don't need to build your own application, Microsoft has already built one for you. It's ingeniously called [BCP Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx). If needed, you can create a [format file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx) that tells BCP Utility how to import your data. The best part is it's ridiculously fast and you can import the data to SQL Server from a remote machine (as in the file doesn't have to be located on the SQL Server box to import it)

To address the fact that you need to be able to change the column widths, I don't think editing the format file would be to bad.

Ideally you would be able to use a delimited format instead of an ever-changing fixed length format, that would make things much easier. It might be quick and easy for you to import the data into excel and save it in a delimited format and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Excel, Access, all the flavors of VB and C# have easy-to-use drivers for treating text files as virtual database tables, usually with visual aids for mapping the columns. And reading and writing to SQL Server is of course cake. I'd start there.

100K rows should not be a problem unless maybe you're doing it hourly for several clients.

Comment: Could you give me an example of such a driver?

Comment: Here's a whole bestiary of them, from ODBC to LINQ. Combine any acronym with the source type and destination you want, and google should be your friend. http://devblog.virtage.com/2009/02/microsoft-database-technologies-babylon-odbc-ole-db-ado-jet-isam-mdac-linq/

Answer (score 0):

I'd come across [File Helpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/quick_start_fixed.html) a while back when I was looking for a CSV parser. The example I've linked to shows you how you can use basic POCOs decorated with attributes to represent the file you are trying to parse. Therefore you'd need a Customer specific POCO in order to parse their files.

I haven't tried this myself, but it could be worth a look.